# Writing a translator similar to pig latin

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java where I'm supposed to translate an English sentence to a language similar to pig Latin just with a few different rules.
So far I've written the code, but it only seems to translate one word at a time rather than a whole sentence. can you let me know where I went wrong? Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a phrase to convert: ");

        String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
            char firstLetter = (words[i].charAt(0));
            if (firstLetter == 'a' || firstLetter == 'e' || firstLetter == 'i' || firstLetter == 'o' || firstLetter == 'u'){
                String vowel = words[i] +"-eh";
                System.out.print(vowel);
            }else{
                String start = words[i].substring(0,1);
                String end = words[i].substring(1,phrase.length());
                System.out.print(end + "-" + start + "eh" );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( );
    }
}
```

Comment: • A  word that starts with a vowel has “-eh” added to the end.   
Egg becomes egg-eh, open becomes open-eh, ultimate becomes ultimate-eh.
• A word that starts with a single consonant, will have the consonant moved to the end of the word, then add the ‘eh’

word becomes ord-weh,  mainly becomes ainly-meh

• A word that starts with 2 or 3 consonants does not get changed at all.
Spain remains Spain.   Three remains three.

Comment: and this is what the input is : The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plain but the ants in France stay mainly on the plants.

Comment: and the output is supposed to be: The ain-reh in-eh Spain stays ainly-meh on-eh the plain ut-beh the ants-eh in-eh France stay ainly-meh on-eh the plants

Comment: This is a brand new question. I think you should start another post.